The message published in RabbitMQ is not being delivered. How can i solve this problem?
I developed chatting process with spring boot, stomp, rabbit mq .
When I tried load testing with JMETER, I expected all messages to be delivered, but they were not.
"I structured the test sequence as shown in the image below."
[Test Sequence]https://i.sstatic.net/UDZBffZE.png)
And This is BeanShell Sampler
String STOMP_SEND_RABBIT = "SEND\n" + 
    "destination:/pub/message.${__threadNum}\n" + 
    "content-length:20\n" + 
    "\n" +  
    "{\"message\":\"hihihi\"}\u0000"; 
   

String STOMP_SUBSCRIBE_RABBIT = "SUBSCRIBE\n" + "id:${__threadNum}\n" + "destination:/exchange/chat.exchange/room.${__threadNum}\n" + "\n" +
      "\u0000";

String STOMP_UNSUBSCRIBE = "UNSUBSCRIBE\n" + "id:${__threadNum}\n" + "\n" + "\u0000";

String STOMP_CONNECT = "CONNECT\n" + "accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0\n" + "heart-beat:0,0\n" + 
      "Authorization:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3Mjg4ODY4MTksInN1YiI6ImRpb25pc29zMTk4IiwiYXV0aCI6Ik5PUk1BTCJ9.UG9PHKKVWecjERKkmQNaQEvdAuGMXnM6WvJJX0zmWFQm41-Rhav-5VdXHzI9DsNK20rVE7nMtRtTM2xiBbiMhg\n" + "\n" +              "\u0000";
String STOMP_DISCONNECT = "DISCONNECT\n" + "receipt:close-0\n" + "\n" + "\u0000";

vars.put("s", s);
vars.put("STOMP_SEND", STOMP_SEND);
vars.put("STOMP_SUBSCRIBE", STOMP_SUBSCRIBE);
vars.put("STOMP_CONNECT", STOMP_CONNECT);
vars.put("STOMP_DISCONNECT", STOMP_DISCONNECT);
vars.put("STOMP_UNSUBSCRIBE", STOMP_UNSUBSCRIBE);
vars.put("STOMP_SUBSCRIBE_RABBIT",STOMP_SUBSCRIBE_RABBIT);
vars.put("STOMP_SEND_RABBIT",STOMP_SEND_RABBIT);

And The Thread Properties are
"Number of Threads": 80
"Ramp-up period":1,
"LoopCount":1
"However, as shown in the picture below, some chat rooms do not receive the messages."
Do not receive Message
When this issue occurs, not always but occasionally, the following error is displayed in Spring Boot."
TCP connection failure in session 34ec83a2-93d0-bbb1-036c-52c3eb5355ea: failed to forward SEND /topic/message.68 session=34ec83a2-93d0-bbb1-036c-52c3eb5355ea application/json payload={"headers":{},"body":null,"statusCode":"OK","statusCodeValue":200}
 Connection has been closed BEFORE send operation

OR
TCP connection failure in session 22edcca6-2244-bdb8-275a-6b1106c135ff: Transport failure: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:255) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]

And Here is Rabbit MQ and Stomp Settings
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {

    private static final String CHAT_QUEUE_NAME = "chat.queue";
    private static final String CHAT_EXCHANGE_NAME = "chat.exchange";
    private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "room.*";

    @Value("${rabbit.host}")
    private String rabbitHost;

    @Value("${rabbit.id}")
    private String rabbitId;

    @Value("${rabbit.pw}")
    private String rabbitPw;

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {

        RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange());
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(chatQueue());
        rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(bindingKeroro(exchange(), chatQueue()));


        return rabbitAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(CHAT_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue chatQueue() {
        return new Queue(CHAT_QUEUE_NAME, true);
    }


    @Bean
    public Binding bindingKeroro(DirectExchange exchange, Queue chatQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(chatQueue).to(exchange).with(ROUTING_KEY);
    }


    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setExchange(CHAT_EXCHANGE_NAME);
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

  
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

        factory.setHost(rabbitHost);
        factory.setUsername(rabbitId);
        factory.setPassword(rabbitPw);

        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}

Stomp Setting
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final StompErrorHandler stompErrorHandler;
    private final StompPreHandler stompPreHandler;

    @Value("${rabbit.host}")
    private String rabbitHost;

    @Value("${rabbit.id}")
    private String rabbitId;

    @Value("${rabbit.pw}")
    private String rabbitPw;

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-stomp")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
  
        registry.setErrorHandler(stompErrorHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

                registry.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."))
                .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub")
                .enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic", "/exchange", "/amq/queue")
                .setRelayHost(rabbitHost)
                .setVirtualHost("/")
                .setRelayPort(61613)
                .setSystemLogin(rabbitId)
                .setSystemPasscode(rabbitPw)
                .setClientLogin(rabbitId)
                .setClientPasscode(rabbitPw);

    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(stompPreHandler);
    }


}


And I Think there is nothing special on rabbit mq log file
2024-10-15 11:48:37.774531+00:00 [info] <0.90754.0> connection <0.90754.0> (172.17.0.1:45624 -> 172.17.0.2:5672) has a client-provided name: connectionFactory#1268dff4:0
2024-10-15 11:48:37.780955+00:00 [info] <0.90754.0> connection <0.90754.0> (172.17.0.1:45624 -> 172.17.0.2:5672 - connectionFactory#1268dff4:0): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'   
2024-10-15 11:48:39.329923+00:00 [info] <0.90769.0> accepting STOMP connection <0.90769.0> (172.17.0.1:59766 -> 172.17.0.2:61613)
2024-10-15 11:48:47.195528+00:00 [info] <0.90769.0> closing STOMP connection <0.90769.0> (172.17.0.1:59766 -> 172.17.0.2:61613)
2024-10-15 11:48:47.210609+00:00 [info] <0.90794.0> accepting STOMP connection <0.90794.0> (172.17.0.1:59778 -> 172.17.0.2:61613)
2024-10-15 11:48:47.225363+00:00 [info] <0.90794.0> closing STOMP connection <0.90794.0> (172.17.0.1:59778 -> 172.17.0.2:61613)
2024-10-15 11:48:50.043699+00:00 [info] <0.90754.0> closing AMQP connection <0.90754.0> (172.17.0.1:45624 -> 172.17.0.2:5672 - connectionFactory#1268dff4:0, vhost: '/', user: 'guest')

Any Ideas?

Try increasing JMeter logging verbosity for the WebSocket Samplers by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file:
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />

This way you will be able to see outgoing and incoming requests and responses details and also will be able to tell who and why closed the connection.
And also reconsider using Beanshell, it's some form of a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language instead. See Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for more details.
